# Which AWS region should I pick if I want to host an international web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am building a web application that will be offered in many different languages. I want the web application to be accessible to people from all continents. Right now I have picked an american AWS region but this may not be the best region because both Asia and Europe are on the other side of an ocean.

I am looking for a region that is most central to all the other continents. In other words, a region where most of my end users will have about the same latency when browsing the web application.

My guess is that the AWS region should be Frankfurt because aside from europe both Asia and Africa are relatively close to that region. But maybe i got it all wrong and the best spot would be an American one.

So my question is: Which region is best if you want to host an international web application.

Thank you

Comment: You could stand up a simple webapp in Europe and then test accessing it from various points on the globe using online latency testers or by utilizing EC2 clients in various regions around the world. CDN (CloudFront or other) will be a major consideration for you. Also, if at some point you consider doing this multi-region then watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2e29I3dA8o4.

Comment: Unless you have a mission critical application choose the cheapest region, in particular if you plan to use an EC2 instance. Then as jarmod already said put CloudFront on top of it, which will deal with serving content to the closest user  location. I have my websites running in Ohio since years, and from Europe I cannot see any significant delay. Depending on the components you are planning to use, you can move almost always them between regions. One interesting thing you should do while you are still developing, is to invest some little resources and take some measurement and metrics.

Comment: @Leonardo, The cheapest EC2 instance is located in china or south korea. But when i browse chinese/korean websites from home (in the netherlands) they all take about 4 seconds to load. Thats allot of latency. So I assume you are saying that i should pick the cheapest region in either europe or america right? American websites typically take only 2 seconds on average to load. So connectivity between America and Europe must be allot better then between Asia and Europe

Comment: @Jarmod thx for the link!

Comment: @Leonardo, nevermind what i said about china/south korea EC2s being the cheapest. I was accidentally comparing nano prices with medium prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you should **deploy your application in a region closer to the 'majority' of your target users**.
Reason: Physical distance cannot be influenced by any means.

Second, **use Serverless technologies from AWS** (Lambda, API Gateway, StepFunctions etc) so that you can infinitely (technically) scale them based on your needs and are flexible for global user base scenarios, like yours.

Third, **make best use of CDN** (content delivery network) from AWS -- i.e. CloudFront -- to distribute your app globally.
Reason: CDN will make sure to cache static parts of your app closer to your target user's geographical location, thus helps in loading your app (and its contents) faster.

Lastly, **use Global DNS** (Route53's GeoLocation Routig) for faster DNS name lookups.
Reason: By distributing DNS lookups geographically (into every continent), and by hooking up Route53 with CloudFrot (local to that continent); you will have a short-line of communication from your end users.

HTH,

cheers!

Comment: At this point its impossible to know where the majority of the users will be coming from. The application will first be released in english only. But I will be adding new languages in the months after launch. Also, It is a spring boot application that already has an API defined using spring controller classes. So i don't know if i can use API Gateway.

Comment: You should be able to deploy Sprint Boot app on AWS Lambda (which means, it can easily be exposed over AWS API Gateway to external world). Get started [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot). 

With CloudFront + API Gateway combination, you get the power of caching static content across the world (local to your target user base) so that it can be served very quickly (as I said.. physical distance cannot be influenced by any other means other than caching content local to the users location).

Comment: Serverless on AWS (or any cloud) doesn't scale infinitely, technically or otherwise.

Comment: @RamGrandhi Can i use EC2 instead of Lambda? I mean I can scale with EC2 as well right?

Comment: @Maurice - You can use EC2 too. But, your infra design would look more complicated, I'm afraid. With EC2 as compute, for a globally distributed app; the flow would be like this  :: **EC2 instances in Auto-scaling mode** _per region_ ===> _frontended by_ **Application Load Balancer** _per region_ ===> _frontended by_ **Cloud Front Distributions** _one per each region pointing to the ALB endpoint(s)_ ===> **Route53 Geo-Location Routing** _one A-record per Continent pointing to the CloudFront Distribution endpoint in that continent_. Hth!

Comment: @RamGrandhi, is it ok to start out with EC2 though? I mean i won't expect to get millions of visits right away. After how much traffic would you recommend me to switch from EC2 to Lambda? 1 million visits a month or so?Thx

Comment: If you ask this question 3 years ago, my answer would have been ‘OK Sure’. But we are in 2020 when Serverless technologies are the new normal (for apps and websites), I wouldnt recommend investing in IaaS (EC2 etc) since it might give you headstart in the beginning but would soon feel like a limiting factor. Also the cost is multifold with IaaS. You are the best judge for your situation, with all this information. Please take call.